# Are all review audits always revealed after you answer?

Tags: support, review-audits

I was just reviewing a few low quality posts, and getting up a bit of speed. I found a fairly strange Answer with something about "college interview" in it and it dawned on me that this was most likely my first ever honest-to-goodness link spam.

So I selected the Delete option. There is no choice for "spam" so I just left the default and on to the next question.

It was then I realised that the Question was probably spam too, so I tried to find it so I could mark that for deletion too. Nothing on search and it never showed up in my review actions. That should mean it was an audit test, but there was no "that was an audit test and you passed" message.

So my question is: are there silent audits? Is it expected that some audits will not reveal themselves?

---

Another possibility: maybe the question was deleted. So, the question then is: are there reviews which disappear retrospectively, because something was deleted that made the review inapplicable?

Comment: Could be that it got deleted before you decided what to do with it.  Other people are looking at the queues too.  :)

Comment: @cHao: I guess the _question_ might have been deleted. It was only a few seconds, but could be. See edit.

Comment: I thought that audits were still recorded in review history, they just look the same as the rest until you click through to them.